# Change and show dropdown value based on another drop down selection in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the following dropdown in my HTML:

```
<td colspan="2" width="100%">
    <mat-form-field class="generate-full-width">
    <mat-select placeholder="Product" formControlName="product" name="product" (selectionChange)="getDefaultValues()">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.value">
                                                    {{product.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="submitted && hasError('product', 'required')">Product is required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</td>
```

For each product, I am populating in some fields. Each product has three values associated with it, which I need to show when a product is selected. One of these fields is a drop-down, in HTML like this:

```
<td colspan="2" width="100%">
    <mat-form-field class="generate-full-width">
    <mat-select placeholder="Max Users" formControlName="maxUsers" name="maxUsers">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let user of maxUsers" [value]="user.value">
                                                {{user.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="submitted && hasError('maxUsers', 'required')">Max Users is required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>  
</td>
```

The `getDefaultValues()` method in my ts file is this:

```
let defaultArray = this.getDefaultConfig().filter((item) => {
    return item.id === product;
});
        
this.form.get('maxUsers').setValue(defaultArray[0].maxUsers)
this.form.get('value2').setValue(defaultArray[0].value2);
this.form.get('value3').setValue(defaultArray[0].value3);
```

The `getDefaultConfig()` method is:

```
let defaultProductConfig: any=[];
    this.allProducts.forEach(element => {
      
      defaultProductConfig.push
        ({"id": element["productId"],
        "maxUsers" : element["maxUsers"],
        "value2": element["value2"],
        "value3": element["value3"]});
    });
    
    return defaultProductConfig;
  }
```

When I select a product, the value2 and value3 are populated. They are text fields. But the maxUsers value is not populated. It has a list of permissible values, and each product will have those values only. They are defined as:

```
maxUsers = [
    { value: '30', viewValue: '30' },
    { value: '60', viewValue: '60' },
    { value: '90', viewValue: '90' },
    { value: '120', viewValue: '120' },
    { value: '150', viewValue: '150' },
    { value: '180', viewValue: '180' },
    { value: '1200', viewValue: 'Unlimited' }
  ]
```

How to populate this field too, according to the product selected?

Comment: Does `this.allProducts` elements have `maxUsers`?

Comment: it has values in an array like this: 0: {productId: "product0", maxUsers: 0, value2: 0, value3: 0}
1: {productId: "product1", maxUsers: 0, value2: 0, value3: 0}
2: {productId: "product2", maxUsers: 0, value2: 0, value3: 0}
3: {productId: "product3", maxUsers: 30, value2: 100, value3: 10000}
4: {productId: "product4", maxUsers: 60, value2: 100, value3: 10000}
5: {productId: "product5", maxUsers: 90, value2: 1000, value3: 100000}
6: {productId: "product6", maxUsers: 180, value2: 2000, value3: 1000000}
7: {productId: "product7", maxUsers: 30, value2: 10, value3: 5000}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `maxUsers` in the `product` is number. Try removing the quote of `value`.

```
maxUsers = [
    { value: 30, viewValue: '30' },
    { value: 60, viewValue: '60' },
    { value: 90, viewValue: '90' },
    { value: 120, viewValue: '120' },
    { value: 150, viewValue: '150' },
    { value: 180, viewValue: '180' },
    { value: 1200, viewValue: 'Unlimited' }
  ]
```